# Complex SQLite Join

Tags: sqlite

I have a table (tbl) with 3 fields: id, date and status. Sample information from the table might look as follows:

```
id date status
 1 8-20 open
 2 8-20 open
 3 8-20 closed
 4 8-21 closed
 5 8-22 open
 6 8-23 open
 7 8-24 closed
```

I want to write a query that returns the data as follows:

```
date open closed
8-20 2    1
8-21 0    1
8-22 1    0
8-23 1    0
8-24 0    1
```

The closest I can seem to get is wrapping two unioned selects in another select like so:

```
select date from (
select date, count(id) from tbl where status = 'open' group by date
union
select date, count(id) from tbl where status = 'closed' group by date)
group by date
```

I would think it would involve a full outer join if it wasn't SQLite to account for the days where one of the statuses has 0 entries but I don't know how I would structure the two left joins to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use correlated subqueries for this:

```
SELECT date,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tbl AS t2
        WHERE t2.date = tbl.date
         AND status = 'open'
       ) AS open,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tbl AS t2
        WHERE t2.date = tbl.date
         AND status = 'closed'
       ) AS closed
FROM tbl
```

Alternatively, group by the date, and count how many rows in the group have the desired status:

```
SELECT date,
       total(status = 'open') AS open,
       total(status = 'closed') AS closed
FROM tbl
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: The second query pulled the data correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run the following query:

```
select date, sum(case when status ='open' then 1 else 0 end) as open from test group by date
```

[sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0c533/4](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0c533/4)

and do the same for closed.